# Stop Dataguard configuration to test standby database

Tags: oracle, transparent-data-encryption, dataguard, testing

I would like to know how it would be the correct way in which I should proceed to stop the Dataguard configuration in order to perform a series of tests on the standby database.
It turns out that I have an environment with two Oracle 11gR2 databases, one primary and the other physical standby in a remote location (DR), the fact is that I have to perform some stress tests, modifications in some logical structures and above all, apply TDE to column level and measure the performance after applying it, all these actions I would like to do in the physical standby since it is impossible to stop the production database as it is very critical. So, as I was saying, the idea is to momentarily stop Dataguard, perform all operations on standby, and then return everything to the way it was before. What steps should I take to carry out the task in question?

Comment: You should have a dedicated test environment for this. The alterations - especially logical ones like encrypting columns; anything that affects the logical model of the database - must be made in the primary database and replicated to the alternate database. You won't be able to resync if you make changes to the standby.

Comment: I was thinking about the possibility of converting the physical standby into a standby snapshot, running the tests and putting it back in its initial state (physical standby), but I don't know if it would be a good idea, I am particularly concerned about how it would work with TDE. Any ideas? any suggestions? Someone who has been through something similar?

Comment: you have no test environment to do this in? you shouldn't have to change your production configuration to perform these kinds of tests. If something doesn't go as planned you will have compromised your DR capability, which could seriously affect your business. It is possible you might even need downtime to correct the problem, and you still wouldn't have your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested you should convert the physical standby database into a snapshot standby database. You can do almost all changes on the snapshot standby database, except for TDE operations.
To do TDE stuff you must have a keystone and a TDE master key. This you create on the primary database, and copy it to the standby database.
Part of the TDE configuration goes into the control file, so you can't undo that with Flashback Database (which is used by snapshot standby database).